# Is there a way to create a file explorer in angular to access a local folder and its sub folders using angular 6?

Tags: angular6

I've been trying for some days to develop a file explorer inside may angular application to access local folders and files and perform operations on them such as read write. I've developed an explorer, but its not allowing me to access the local folders and files, instead it is creating it's own folders. I used this link to develop the explorer.

https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-file-explorer-component/

Answer (score 1):

We can do it by creating custom component for displaying the file manager folders and files. The Folder and files structure can be fetched from your API.
[The link to the client side is available in this example created by @LucasMarx](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-explorer)